# Why mongodb source always return the entire documents but not new added document

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

this is the DSL using to create mongodb source ingestion to log:

```
stream create --name mongodb7hdfs7 --definition 
    "mongodb120 
    --database=sourcedb 
    --host=172.20.74.91 
    --fixed-delay=5 
    --cron='*/10 * * * * *' 
    --initial-delay=5 
    --max-messages=1 
    --collection=sourceCol | log" --deploy
```

When monitoring the log, it can always see the entire documents of the collection are ingested to the sink. But what we expect is to see only new added document will be ingested to the sink. In the monitored log, we would see all the documents of the collection being printed in the log every 10 seconds. But the expected result is supposed to only see the latest added document being printed.

Can someone help on this? Much appreciated!
BTW, the http source is always only ingesting new added data to the sink.

Comment: using maven://org.springframework.cloud.stream.app:mongodb-source-rabbit:1.2.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT from repo: http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot-local
Are they both correct?